# QNetworkRequest (HTTP GET) doesn't fire, after refactoring into a standalone class

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

I've recently began the tedious process of modularising a large, monolithic audio player application that I wrote roughly 2 months ago.

This process is going reasonably well, although it appears that one of the methods (ScrobbleMedia - which predictably enough makes HTTP requests to submit information about a playing track to last.fm) no longer seems to make network requests.

However, the QUrl object that would be passed through to the QNetworkAccessManager instance/QNetworkRequest is being built correctly.

For comparison, a functional Mercurial revision of the code is available on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/vmlemon/audioplayer/src/b655a64e824a/audioplayer.cpp).

The ScrobbleMedia method currently looks like this, after refactoring:

```
#include "scrobblemedia.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <cstdio>

ScrobbleMedia::ScrobbleMedia(QString asUsername, QString asPassword,
                         QString asArtist, QString asTrack, QString asAlbum)
{

    QString KEndPointURL = "http://lastfmstats.livefrombmore.com/universalscrobbler/scrobble.php";
    QUrl iScrobbleEndPoint(KEndPointURL);

      QNetworkAccessManager *iScrobbleDispatcher = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);


iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("submissionType","track");
iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("username", asUsername);
iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("password", asPassword);
iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("artist", asArtist);
iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("track", asTrack);
iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("album", asAlbum);
iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("number","1");
iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("duration","200");

iScrobbleDispatcher->get(QNetworkRequest(iScrobbleEndPoint));
connect(iScrobbleDispatcher, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
 SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

// QString Outside = iScrobbleEndPoint.toEncoded();

qDebug()  << "Received: " + 
  asUsername + " " + 
   asPassword + " " + 
    asArtist + " " +
     asTrack + " " + 
      asAlbum;

qDebug() << iScrobbleEndPoint.toString();

}

ScrobbleMedia::~ScrobbleMedia() {

}
```

The associated header file looks like:

```
#ifndef SCROBBLEMEDIA_H
#define SCROBBLEMEDIA_H

#include <QString>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>



class ScrobbleMedia : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT;


private:

public:

    ScrobbleMedia(QString asUsername, QString asPassword, QString asArtist, QString asTrack, QString asAlbum);
    ~ScrobbleMedia();

};

#endif // SCROBBLEMEDIA_H
```

I'm currently building the application itself against a MinGW build of version 4.7.0 of the Qt libraries (included as part of Qt SDK 2010.05) under Windows 7 x86-64.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two questions: Why there is a semicolon after the Q_OBJECT macro? Why there is no replyFinished() slot declared in the header? If you're on Windows, you may wish to recompile your project using CONFIG+=console qmake option, as it will allow you to see run-time Qt warnings (like "no such slot" messages).

Comment: Thanks, Sergey. I'll update the code tonight, and let you know what happens (since I haven't got a Qt toolchain handy at the moment). The semicolon was habitual, and I was unsure as to whether or not it'd make a difference.

Comment: @Tyson, also you should provide your version of Qt SDK. There are many issues with QNAM and finished() signal for older versions of Qt.

Comment: @Johnny I'm using Qt SDK 4.7.0 (built against MinGW by Nokia) under Windows 7 x86-64. I apologise for the confusing comment updates, since I've just double-checked against a copy of QtCore4.dll that I obtained from another project that I built against the same SDK version.

Comment: That said, I'll also update to the latest version of the SDK tonight.

Comment: I've since made @Sergey Tachenov's suggestions, and it appears that compilation bails out with `../AudioPlayer/scrobblemedia.h:24: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'replyFinished' with no type`. I'm still investigating that.

Comment: Looks like a stupid mistake on my part - I forgot to declare it void! Oops. Now it's just a case of resolving a `debug/moc_scrobblemedia.o:C:\Users\Tyson Key\Desktop\Projects\AudioPlayer-build-desktop/debug/moc_scrobblemedia.cpp:72: undefined reference to `ScrobbleMedia::replyFinished()'` error.

Comment: @Tyson, as for the semicolon, it's especially dangerous to put it after a macro which expands to only god and the Trolls know what. But even not considering that, using extra semicolons anywhere except within a function body is pretty dangerous by itself, and it can break on many compilers.

Comment: @Tyson, undefined reference simply means that you have declared it in the class, but haven't defined it in the implementation file. (Like, forgot to add `ScrobbleMedia::`.)

Comment: Thanks. After adding `void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);` to the `private slots:` section of `scrobblemedia.h`, updating the `connect()` call to `QObject::connect(iScrobbleDispatcher, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(quit()));` and adding an empty `void ScrobbleMedia::replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)` method to `scrobblemedia.cpp` it appears that the project compiles successfully again. However, it doesn't quite solve the "nothing reaches the network" problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a number of different sources of information (most of which were contradictory), I've found that the following results in a working solution - albeit with a cosmetic issue in the debugging output that doesn't seem to affect operation (`Object::connect: No such signal QNetworkReplyImpl::finished(QNetworkReply*) in ../AudioPlayer/scrobblemedia.cpp:29`):

In `scrobblemedia.cpp`:

```
#include "scrobblemedia.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <cstdio>

ScrobbleMedia::ScrobbleMedia(QString asUsername, QString asPassword,
                             QString asArtist, QString asTrack, QString asAlbum)
{

    QByteArray iDataSink;
    QEventLoop iLoop;

    QString KEndPointURL = "http://lastfmstats.livefrombmore.com/universalscrobbler/scrobble.php";
    QUrl iScrobbleEndPoint(KEndPointURL);

    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("submissionType","track");
    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("username", asUsername);
    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("password", asPassword);
    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("artist", asArtist);
    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("track", asTrack);
    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("album", asAlbum);
    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("number","1");
    iScrobbleEndPoint.addQueryItem("duration","200");

    QNetworkAccessManager iScrobbleDispatcher;
    QNetworkRequest iScrobbleRequest(iScrobbleEndPoint);
    QNetworkReply *iScrobbleReply = iScrobbleDispatcher.get(iScrobbleRequest);

    QObject::connect(iScrobbleReply, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &iLoop,
     SLOT(quit()));

    iDataSink = iScrobbleReply->readAll();

    qDebug()  << "Received: " + asUsername + " " + asPassword + " " + asArtist + " " + asTrack + " " + asAlbum;

    qDebug() << iScrobbleEndPoint.toString();

    iLoop.exec();
}

ScrobbleMedia::~ScrobbleMedia() {

}

void ScrobbleMedia::replyFinished(QNetworkReply*) {

}

void ScrobbleMedia::reallyDone() {

    qDebug() << "We've probably successfully Scrobbled...";
}
```

In `scrobblemedia.h`:

```
#ifndef SCROBBLEMEDIA_H
#define SCROBBLEMEDIA_H

#include <QString>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>



class ScrobbleMedia : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT


private:


public:

    ScrobbleMedia(QString asUsername, QString asPassword, QString asArtist, QString asTrack, QString asAlbum);
    ~ScrobbleMedia();

private slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);
    void reallyDone();

};

#endif // SCROBBLEMEDIA_H
```

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Hopefully this code will serve as a useful template for others, in the future.

Comment: Where exactly the reallyDone() slot is called? I don't see it in the code. Why do you need an event loop? If it's not a multi-threading application, then using a separate event loop is unnecessary at least or maybe even dangerous. And finally, your issue isn't "cosmetic". You get it because you're trying to connect to a non-existent signal `finished(QNetworkReply*)` in iScrobbleReply. It only has the finished() signal with no parameters. It's the QNetworkAccessManager that has the finished() slot with a QNetworkReply* parameter. That's why your quit() method will never get called.

Comment: reallyDone() isn't called anywhere - it's just left over from a previous attempt at getting things to work. The event loop idea was suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572985/how-can-i-use-qt-to-get-html-code-of-the-redirected-page, and seemed to work in my case.

Comment: With that in mind, I've removed `reallyDone()`, and defined `void finished(QNetworkReply*)`, in addition to providing a stub implementation of it. The code itself still works (I can see HTTP requests in Wireshark), but handling the "bottomless slots" problem cleanly is something for later, since I've got to leave to go somewhere soon.

Comment: Update: I've updated the `connect()` call to `QObject::connect(iScrobbleReply, SIGNAL(finished()), &iLoop, SLOT(quit()));`, and it appears that not only does the application still work, but the slot error no longer appears.